# Python: regular expression pattern other than a comma

Tags: python

How can I set the regular expression pattern other than SPECIFIC CHARACTER?

```
import re
str = 'abc?, def/ghi'
match = re.findall(r'[anything other than ',' or \s]', str)

print(match)
['abc?', 'def/ghi']
```

THX!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the straight forward

```
[^,]
```

which means exactly what you said.  Did you even *bother* reading a regexp documentation? ;-)

For all except a comma and whitespace you can use the same approach:

```
[^,\s]
```

And to get a sequence of those use this:

```
[^,\s]+
```